Relation between Unity of Apperception and judgements in Kant
Insofar, what I've got is that for anything to be (in my perception as a subject), it needs to be synthesized into a set that belongs specifically to me, i.e., anything that appears to me should be possibly accompanied by the "I think". I should be able to call every single representation I have as "mine". This, then, shows a need for a synthesis, and such unity would be, then, needed for anything to appear to me, since if there wasn't the possibility of noticing the representation as mine, it would be as if it didn't even exist (in my POV). This previous synthesis, in the basis of the mere possibility of any representation (and, therefore, object, since analytic unity also pressupposes this synthetic unity of the Principle of Apperception), is what is really objective, since it's a condition to any representation.
Now, what I didn't get is how this is related to judgements in any degree. I mean, I do agree that we need this synthesis, that we need to be able to call every representation ours. Now, how does this translate into a "for an object to exist for us, it needs to conform itself to the form of judgement"? What is the relation between the Synthetic Unity of Appercetion, which is this a priori synthesis that unifies every single rep. into a single Self, and judgements at all? Because as soon as I understand this, I think it gets pretty intuitive to reach the Categories (and the reason they're related to every single object, since they would be the condition for them to exist for us in the first place in case every object needs to be in the form of judgements). Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

The form of judgement is one of the most important transcendental schemata without which no experiential judgment would be possible to each empirical synthesis, and such transcendence provides judgment with a rule under which given empirical intuitions are to be subsumed insofar as the rule such as for bats to hear those which humans cannot hear can be established by whatever mechanism and is utilized and controlled by both the Kantian categories and senses..

Apperception is one of Kant’s basic technical terms. The term is introduced in Critique of pure Reason (CpR), Section: Transcendental Analytic, B131:

It must be possible for the I think to accompany all my
representations: for otherwise something would be represented within
me that could not be thought at all, in other words, the
representation would either be impossible, or at least would be
nothing for me. That representation which can be given prior to all
thought is called intuition, and all the manifold of intuition has,
therefore, a necessary relation to the I think in the same subject in
which this manifold of intuition is found. This representation (the I
think), however is an act of spontaneity, that is, it cannot be
considered as belonging to sensibility. I call it pure apperception,
in order to distinguish it from empirical apperception, or also
original apperception …

According to Kant it is the person who constructs experience – in the sense of modern constructivism. Experience is more than just taking an image. Experience is an active mental construction, based on one hand on our intuition and on the other hand on the 12 categories. I consider this mental activity to be what Kant names “pure apperception”.
I am sure that there are other participants on this side who can provide a deeper interpretation of Kant’s terms and idea, and I am also curious to hear their thoughts. :-)

Not sure I got this right, but I was thinking that the empirical unity of apperception is the thought-I, tye one I have access to in "I think," and the pure unity of apperception is the thinking-I, which is a precondition of synthesis in consciousness.  I can infer it, but the moment I think it, it is  already thought, already synthesized or conceptually recognized.

Apperception (self-consciousness), in its pure form, consists of two sides: the analytic unity of apperception (AUA) — the "I think" —, and the synthetic unity of apperception (SUA). SUA can be defined by its "individuality, while AUA can be defined by its "universality": by attaching AUA to any ordinary representation it's possible to convert it in an concept (universal representation). However, since concepts are, by definition, logical and intellectual in nature, we cannot combine them in the same ways as non-conceptual representations (e.g. by associating them in imagination, etc.). Therefore, it's necessary to synthesize/combine these concepts via the innate logical forms of judgment, so we can unite them in a single act of propositional thought.
The logical forms of judgment makes possible the pure concepts of the understanding (that Kant will want to identify with the categories), since these concepts will derive their content solely from these logical forms, by nullifying the logical freedom of judgments. So, for example, in a categorial judgment, we can relate any concept as a subject to any other concept as a predicate (and vice-versa). If we fix the positions these concepts have in this judgment, we arrive at the notions of "final subject" (something that is always a subject) and "final predicate" (something that is always a predicate), which will constitute the pure concepts of substance and accident.
Finally, regarding the SUA: even though AUA and SUA analytically imply each other, SUA precedes AUA and makes it possible, since a consciousness that is common to all representations implies a consciousness that individually unites all possible representations within it. SUA is a pure, formal individuality that cannot incorporate anything universal in its representations, and will be nothing but the unity of sensibility which, in beings constituted like us, is effected by the formal intuitions of space and time.
To sum up: (1) SUA is produced by the unity of sensibility (space + time); (2) with SUA, AUA becomes possible as well; (3) by attaching AUA to representations, they are converted in concepts; (4) we combine these concepts via logical forms of judgment; and (5) we arrive at the pure concepts of the understanding by nullifying the logical freedom of the forms of judgment.

So, basically, in order for me to have any representations, I should be able to unify them into a set (my representations). Since the "I think" is, itself, a judgement, and I have to attach them to something in order for it to exist to me, then an object can only exist whether it's subject to the form of judgements. These are ruled by 12 logical functions, and these logical functions, therefore, are the responsibles for the very possibility of an object. When they're applied to objects, they're called Categories, which are necessary due to the exposed. Is that right?
